# Find intervals where f is continuous, $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+x+1}$

Tags: calculus

Find intervals where f is continuous, $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+x+1}$. I would appreciate any help. I know that $x^2+x+1$ is continuous, but I'm not sure how to deal with the composition of this function with the square root function - and I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that the radicand must be positive for the function to be defined at all.

Comment: What's getting you stuck on this problem? Would you, for instance, be able to show that $x^2+x+1$ is continuous? Can you reason about where $x^2+x+1$ is non-negative?

Comment: I know the radicand cant be negative. I'm not sure if I would have to solve the quadratic inequality or not.  I know the polynomial X^2+x+1 is continuous. The limit as x approaches say, c, would be equal to f(c). I can't figure out how to handle the composition of that polynomial and the square root fcn.  Help would be appreciated. I'm sorry for the simplistic question. I'm teaching myself, no professor.I would appreciate some help. the steps on how to do this would be great

Comment: I could use help reasoning where x^2+x+1 is negative.

Comment: @phil, you might want to put your previous comment in your question body. To answer your question, $x^2 + x +1$ is never negative.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you already have a few of the ingredients needed to prove the continuity of this function.

A rather crucial property of continuity is that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous - this is certainly something you should seek to prove if you haven't done so before. So, if you can prove  both that $x^2+x+1$ is continuous and that $\sqrt{x}$ is, so must their composition be.

Now, the other consideration is that the square root function requires a positive input, so we need to figure out where $x^2+x+1$ is positive in case the function strays out of the domain of $\sqrt{\cdot}$. There are various ways to do this - the simplest is to plug it into the quadratic formula, see that its roots are $\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$, neither of which is real, implying that it never crosses zero and thus must be positive everywhere. Another somewhat more general way would be to note that $x^2+x+1 \geq 1+x$ (the tangent at $x=1$) and $x^2+x+1 \geq -x$ (a tangent line at $x=-1$), and since one of $1+x$ or $-x$ is positive, $x^2+x+1$ must be as well as it is greater than both.

Putting all this together should allow you to show that $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}$ is a continuous function.